# I can't use phpmyadmin because error "Token mismatch"

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, homebrew

I use phpmyadmin version 4.9.7 shows error 'Error: Token mismatch'

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS4nM.png)

I'm also checked "php.ini" session.save_path ='/tmp' that semicolon is removed and restart nginx via homebrew
but it still show this error, why?

Comment: Do [*not* install or use phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin). Any modern GUI client for Windows/Linux will work much better and more secure.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin "better" is a very subjective term. While MySQL Workbench is an adequate tool, this doesn't mean that PhpMyAdmin is inadequate. It's not professional but is perfectly usable. And it's a *GOOD* thing that PhpMyAdmin has lots of **know** CVEs because that indicates that issues are found, raised and fixed rather than having no public knowledge of any compromises.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I solved this annoying issue by clearing browsing history, cookies and cache.

Also try to open it from another browser.

Comment: I changed to another browser and it works, but why did it happened?

Comment: I had gone after this for long but couldn't figure out exactly what is it but I believe its a bug.

https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3893/